# How can I make ExtJS 4.2.1 empty grid respect flex layout value?

Tags: extjs

SOLUTION:

To better show the problem our actual code was facing, the following code works.

The keys for me to get this to work were to give border layout an 'align' config of stretch, and to ensure that containers had 'flex' config of 1 where necessary.

```
Ext.define('MyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.myGrid',
    columns: [{text: 'First Name'}],
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {fields: ['fname']})
});


Ext.define('MyView', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    alias: 'widget.myView',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'myGrid',
        title: 'My First Grid',
        flex: 7,
        bodyStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#ff0000'
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'myGrid',
        title: 'My Second Grid',
        flex: 3,
        bodyStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#0000ff'
        }
    }]
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            layout: {
                type: 'border',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                region: 'center',
                itemId: 'gridsContainer',
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'myView',
                    flex: 1
                }]
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

---

ORIGINAL POST:

In the code below, if you replace:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Container'
```

with:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport'
```

The grids correctly occupy 70%/30% of the available area.

But when the code has Container and not Viewport, the grids are very small.

Of course my real code is within a larger application, so I cannot use a Viewport at that point, I must use container.

```
Ext.define('MyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.myGrid',
    columns: [{
        text: 'First Name',
        dataIndex: 'fname'
    }],
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['fname']
    })
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            defaults: {
                autoScroll: true,
                bodyPadding: 0
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'myGrid',
                itemId: 'grid1',
                flex: 7
            }, {
                xtype: 'splitter'
            },{
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                itemId: 'mypanel',
                width: 400,
                height: 400,
                renderTo: document.body,
                flex: 3,
                scroll: true,
                resizable: false,
                activeTab: 0,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'myGrid',
                    itemId: 'tabgrid1',
                    title: 'My Grid Tab One'
                },{
                    xtype: 'myGrid',
                    itemId: 'tabgrid2',
                    title: 'My Grid Tab Two'
                }],
                tabBar:{
                    //plain:true,
                    items:[{
                        xtype: 'tbfill'
                    },{
                        text:'????',
                        xtype:'image',
                        src: 'panelCollapseBtn.png',
                        closable: false,
                        listeners:{
                            'afterrender':function (comp) {
                                comp.getEl().on('click', function (el) {
                                    //  alert(comp.up('#mypanel').getCollapsed());
                                    var panel =  comp.up('#mypanel');
                                    var isCollapsed = panel.getCollapsed();
                                    //alert('is collapsed: ' + isCollapsed);
                                    panel.header = !isCollapsed;
                                    //panel.collapsible =isCollapsed;
                                    comp.setSrc(isCollapsed?"panelCollapseBtn.png":"panelExpandBtn.png");
                                    panel.toggleCollapse();

                                }, this);
                                comp.getEl().on('mouseover', function (el) {
                                    el.target.style.cursor = "pointer";
                                }, this);
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Without viewport, the height depends on the height of the most outer container, and in your case it is not set.

Comment: So is there any way to get this to work without explicitly setting heights here?

Comment: You wrote, it is a large application, what layout are you using for the parent panel of this container?

Comment: We're building a dynamically sized app, because the user might resize the browser window, and some might be on laptops with various smaller screen resolutions. Often we just use Container. So do I have to set an explicit size for the parent? Can I do something where I access document.body.clientHeight or is there a better solution?

Comment: Where is the problem to use a viewport?

Comment: My understanding is that an application can have only one Viewport, and that is higher up in this app's container hierarchy.

Comment: yes, that's true. you have to keep each parent container up to the viewport fitting his parent.

Comment: So I guess each sub-container should have layout of fit.

Comment: `fit` if you have only one item in it, or `hbox` or `vbox`but stretched for more items

Comment: What if I want border layout on some pages, and not hbox or vbox?

Comment: I have this working when the app initially renders, but on browser window resize the lower hierarchy of sub-containers do not resize.

Comment: Should I do something on a container resize event, or perhaps afterLayout?

Comment: Any hints on this? resize and afterlayout don't seem to work. Basically after the UI is rendered, even though I am setting the width and height using document.body.clientWidth and document.body.clientHeight, on resize containers lower in hierarchy are not updating.